# External audio interface detected, but no sound from mic

Tags: sound, microphone, interface, audio-recording

I recently bought a Beringer umc22 audio interface, and while Ubuntu seems to detect it, there's no sound from the microphone. I've gone through `pavucontrol` and `alsamixer` to try to un-mute/boost and check everything, but it's still not registering sound. If I turn the 48v amp on and off, it registers sound in audacity, so I'm going to check it with another mic. This mic is brand new though, so I'm more inclined to believe that I'm just missing something.

I recently switched to Ubuntu Studio, hoping this would magically fix everything, but no luck. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC233 Analog [ALC233 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: CODEC [USB Audio CODEC], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ amixer
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-65.25dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-65.25dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 2 [67%] [20.00dB]
  Front Right: 2 [67%] [20.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 63
  Front Left: Capture 63 [100%] [30.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 63 [100%] [30.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Auto-Mute Mode',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
  Item0: 'Disabled'
Simple mixer control 'Digital',0
  Capabilities: cvolume
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 120
  Front Left: Capture 120 [100%] [30.00dB]
  Front Right: Capture 120 [100%] [30.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Loopback Mixing',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
  Item0: 'Disabled'
```

I've played around with a few things in pulse, but it only registers sound from the interface when I turn the preamp on and off.

[image: pulse]

It does the same thing with Audacity. I can talk into the mic and get nothing, but when I turn the preamp off or on from the back of the interface, it registers some kind of signal change.

[image: audacity]

Comment: What is the output of `aplay -l` and `amixer`

Comment: How would I check them? I fished around a bit, but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Run `aplay -l` from the command line and paste the information it generates in your question. Do the same for `amixer` so we have some information about your hardware and settings.

Comment: *added outputs for aplay -l and amixer

Answer (score 0):

It was a bad mic cable... I knew it had to be either that or the mic once I got a signal from the 48v preamp.